# Add big background image to links without empty tags

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

I'm **developing a Drupal 7 theme**, and I'd like to add a big background image to each main menu link but **without using a empty tag**.

You can see a basic layout in [this image](http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/5701/layoutd7theme.jpg).

The red triangle is attached (background) to link1, and the orange one is to link2.

I'd do this in this way:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href=#>Link1<span id="bgimage_link1"></span></a></li>
   <li><a href=#>Link2<span id="bgimage_link2"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

But I wonder if it can be accomplished in another way, without using a empty tag.

Thanks all!

**UPDATE:** [This is what I'm trying to do](http://bit.ly/e2981g) (but without empty tags!)

Comment: In your layout image, it seems that the background image for each link goes beyond its limits, am I right? do the backgrounds of each item intersect?

Comment: Yes, that's why I need a new tag

Comment: Is this Drupal-7-theme-specific?

Comment: no, it's only subtle related to drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this has something to do with Drupal 7, but what is preventing you from doing:

```
<li><a href=#><span id="bgimage_link1">Link1</span></a></li>
```

Do you want the background image to be a clickable part of the link or no? If no, could you do:

```
<li><span id="bgimage_link1"><a href=#>Link1</a></span></li>
```

If yes, why can't you just put the background image on the <a>?

```
<li><a id="bgimage_link1" href=#>Link1</a></li>
```